# Is there way to setup user(!) policy using Minio Java Client API?

Tags: java, policy, minio

I want to have an ability to setup user policy using Minio java SDK.

Based on MINIO UI console I can achieve it by:

1. Add user
2. Add policy
3. Assign policy to user

Is there way to achieve it using Minio Java Client API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minio admin client have the methods that you are looking for.

https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/adminapi/src/main/java/io/minio/admin/MinioAdminClient.java

You can achieve what you described with the following functions in the client.

addUser(..)
addCannedPolicy(..)
setPolicy(...)